# Ios UILabel update performance

Tags: iphone, uilabel

in my application i have an UILabel showing a time updated every second.
I have also draggable objects in the screen.
When I hide the label or i stop the timer everything is perfect but when i start the timer the animation performance of dragging objects go down.
I put the UILabel updating in a separate thread but no luck.
I need help friends :)

Comment: Please post your code in which you are creating the timer, and its selector

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void) onTimer:(NSTimer *)timer;
{

```
timeInterval ++;
int hours = (int)timeInterval / 3600;   

int minutes = (timeInterval %3600)/ 60; 
int seconds = ((timeInterval%3600)%60);
NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d:%02d", hours,minutes,seconds];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(setText:) toTarget:self.time withObject:timeDiff];
```

}

Comment: A label updating once per second causes UI dragging performance to degrade?    Maybe you should also post your dragging code.   Also, you can't update the GUI outside of the main thread.   If you do, it may appear to "work"...until it doesn't, and your app fails in random and unreproducible ways.